# layoutItems order problem

Tags: ide, metadata-api, migration-tool

We have a developer that added a new field to a custom object. It was automatically added to the layout in the last position.

She refreshed her force.com ide fom the server and pushed the change to local code. When she checked it in, the layoutItems section for the objects layout order did not change.

However, the miniLayout order did change to reflect her order.

When the other developers on the team pulled from svn and pushed either via the IDE or migration tool their order was not changed at sf.com, but we all have changed files of this miniLayout that does not match.

This seems like a bug, has anyone else encountered? Any suggested work arounds?

Comment: Have you verified that the field was added to the layout's XML on the dev machines?

Comment: Yep, the field is in the xml, the order seems to be the issue, if I change the regular layout order it seems to auto update the miniLayout order, if I manually reorder the regular field, it seems to work...